# собственная всплывающая подсказка на GoogleMaps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Доброго

Гугловская карта, кликаю на баллут, вылезает подсказка, в моем случае:

```
//1й баллут ( они в цикле проставляются )
var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(00.1,00.1),
    map: map,
    title: '<div id="ballut1" style="width:200px; height:100px; border:1px solid red; margin:10px;">test</div>',
        icon: ballutImg1
    });
```

Подсказка состоит не только из моего DIVа, а вокруг него еще обертка от гугла с кнопкой закрыть. Может ли кто ссылку полезную дать, или кодом удивить, как избавиться от этой обертки и оставить только DIV который я хочу показать

p.s. в интернете есть решения, в основном с кодом в мегабайты размером, что для обучения не подходит

Comment: Как-то так https://jsfiddle.net/svigna/VzYF6/ ?

Comment: при наведении title действительно другой, только вот сама всплывающая подсказка при нажатии все же в гугловской обертке ( это где надпись из примера - This is an info window )

Comment: Ну убрать её (подсказку). Или она нужна? https://jsfiddle.net/anatolysukhanov/81s58th6/

Comment: http://storage1.static.itmages.ru/i/16/0906/h_1473154687_1305632_518145eee6.png ну, если на пальцах, всплывашку охота переделать, а возможно изменить только содержимое внутри нее. ну а title, должен быть отличен от содержимого всплывающей подсказки

Comment: http://en.marnoto.com/2014/09/5-formas-de-personalizar-infowindow.html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у Googlа есть пример показывающий как можно внедрять своё собственное инфо окошко... Кода правда довольно много, но всё очень понятно.

http://googlemaps.github.io/js-samples/infowindow_custom/infowindow-custom.html

Ещё всяких примеров можно накопать тут.
http://googlemaps.github.io/libraries.html

Вот тут с гитхаба можно скачать пример...
https://github.com/googlemaps/js-info-bubble